# Explanations some Python Code

Tags: python, multithreading

this is a basic example of a barrier, of how some threads are waited to enter a barrier for an entrance and another barrier for an exit.
Although the code is fine, I don't really understand in depth how it works...
For instance, I don't understand why a thread that enters the barrier() function, after it does n = n-1, can immediately make n = n+1 and so influence the global n ...? why it seems like all the threads after they make n = n-1 stop somewhere , and then they make n = n+1 in synchronization?

```
import threading
import time
import random
bar1= threading.Semaphore(value=0)
bar2= threading.Semaphore(value=0)
region= threading.Semaphore(value=1)
threads= 10
n= thread
threadlist= []
def usage(x):
    for i in range(2):
        print "[ENTER]: ",x
        barrier()
        print "[EXIT]: ",x
        barrier()

def barrier():
    global bar1,bar2, region,n,threads
    region.acquire();
    n = n - 1;
    if n==0:
        for i in range(threads):
            bar1.release();
    region.release();
    bar1.acquire();
    region.acquire()
    n = n + 1
    if n == threads:
        for i in range(threads):
            bar2.release()
    region.release()
    bar2.acquire()

random.seed()
for i in range(threads):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=usage, args=(i,)) 
    thread.start()
    threadlist.append(thread)
for i in range(len(threadlist)):
    threadlist[i].join()
```

Comment: Could you explain where this code came from and what its goal is?

Comment: This sounds to me like some homework; in this case, my personal suggestion is to just throw it away and implement it from the scratch, because the quality of the fragment is quite poor.

Comment: @Roberto Liffredo. No it's not a homework, it's an example made at the lab..which i didnt understand. if it's poor can you come back with a better variant? thanks

Comment: @David. the goal is purely theoretical.

Comment: @shaku Do you mean to say don't know what it's supposed to do? If you don't care what it should do, why should we?

Comment: @David Heffernan: It's a rendezvous barrier, sometimes also called a HPC barrier, or a cyclic barrier (this last name is the name it has on Java).

Comment: @Roberto Liffredo: care to explain why it looks quite poor to you? To me it looks ok.

Comment: @ninjalj good to see that someone knows what it's all about!

Comment: @David. I know what it does after testing it, just that i didnt have it clear that's all. in the output it gathers numbers 0-9 entrance & exit for a number of times to show that threads enter and exit in order

Comment: @shaku Normally when writing software one starts with a specification and produces code. It's seems odd to start with code and wonder what it is supposed to do. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @David . ah i got it, i should have been more explicit in the beginning

Comment: @shaku I'm guessing that you knew what it was meant to do, but we can't read your mind. Well, I can't anyway. Some more background and explanation would have been helpful.

Comment: @ninjali: For me, quality in software is not only related to correctness. Code may be correct and without bug, but for me, good quality code means something that communicate easily its intent - and for sure, this is not the case. More in detail, using range() is usually a good smell, as well as the usage of global variables or names ending in a number 'bar1', 'bar2'. Of course, they are just hints, but when you couple them with a code that requires effort to be understood, then I think quality is poor. BTW, I _feel_ it could be done more using a job queue, but here I could be completely wrong.

Comment: @Roberto Liffredo: It's pretty clear what it does if you already know what is a rendezvous barrier (a synchronization primitive that lets all users/threads/HPC nodes/... meet at a rendezvous point before proceeding). The name of the function is pretty clear, that should be enough for mere users of the function. What I mean is that you should have a _very good_ reason before suggesting someone to reimplement a synchronization primitive.

Comment: Sure, the code could have some comments, and the critical sections could be shortened a bit (at the expense of code clarity), but my point is that you should'nt mess with a correct implementation of a synchronization primitive without perfect understanding of how it works.

Comment: Oh, and I don't see off-hand how to use a job-queue to do the job of a barrier.

Comment: I mean using the queue to implement it, not to substitute it. But, as I said, I could be completely wrong - that was just a hunch, without any analysis. That said if you read my original comment, I recommended rewriting only in case it was an homework - it is never a good idea to fix code that you do not even know what it does. Even if its quality is suboptimal (and quality, again, is not only a matter of correctness!): if you do not understand it and it works, "if aint broke dont fix it".

Answer (score 2):

`n` is the number of threads that still have to reach the rendezvous point. `region` is a mutex, protecting access to `n`. `bar1` and `bar2` are semaphores, indicating the number of threads that can proceed, initialized to 0.

In the first part of `barrier()`, each thread enters in turn, decreases `n`, and blocks on the `bar1` semaphore. The last thread to enter (the one that makes `n` == 0) posts the semaphore `threads` times, allowing that many threads to proceed.

The second part is symmetrical to the first, this time waiting for the last thread to increment `n`.

Comment: thank you! now it's very clear... the key instruction was bar1.acquire(); which makes the thread which calls it to block.