# What is the meaning of "rendezvous" in computer science?

Tags: multithreading

I remember it was the meeting point in code between few threads (e.g. a border), but I cannot find it on Google. Do you remember such term ?

Comment: Are you talking about "rendez-vous"?

Comment: You're looking for "rendezvous".  http://www.rgoarchitects.com/nblog/2009/08/05/RendezvousThreadSynchronization.aspx

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5291564/371250

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you mean that:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_rendezvous
?

Answer (score 19):

you mean *Rendezvous*. It's also known as HPC Barrier, Rendezvous Barrier, Cyclic Barrier, ...

A Rendezvous Barrier is a synchronization primitive in which threads "meet". Threads that get to the rendezvous point wait until all the threads have reached the rendezvous point, and then they continue.

Comment: How is this different from a "join()"?

Comment: @Chani: join() waits for a thread to end. In a rendezvous barrier (e.g `pthread_barrier_*()`), all threads that want to rendezvous call a _wait_ function, which blocks the calling thread until a number of threads specified when initializing the barrier has called the _wait_ function. All threads can then continue running. See, e.g: _pthread_barrier_init()_ and _pthread_barrier_wait()_.

Answer (score 4):

If you're referring to ["rendez vous"](http://thefreedictionary.com/rendezvous), it's the French for "meeting".

Edit: after googling a bit, it seems the term comes from [Ada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_%28programming_language%29) described as "a method of synchronizing two concurrent tasks for communicating data" by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendezvous).