# Ensure thread has started winapi c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I am creating a program using the winapi in c++.  The program involves two threads.  I create one of the threads using CreateThread.  The problem is that CreateThread doesn't block until the thread is created.  This causes a problem because I am sending messages between the threads, and the thread won't receive any messages until the thread has been created.  How would go about solving this problem.

Comment: why not just wait on some signal from the new thread

Comment: You need a Rendezvous: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454524/what-is-the-meaning-of-rendezvous-in-computer-science

Comment: CreateThread returns **after** the thread is created. It might return before the created thread has started running and initializing its data structures. So what exactly do you need to wait for?

Comment: Until the thread is able to receive messages that are sent to it

Comment: @popgalop: If you're using a proper queue structure then you can enqueue messages even before starting the thread at all.

Comment: @datenwolf the queue instance may be created by the thread before it starts to wait on it for messages?  Usually, I would create any such queue in the thread class ctor before creating the underlying OS thread.

Comment: @MartinJames: What makes you think OP is using a thread class? OP explicitly mentions the `CreateThread` Win32 API function. Also wherever possible any resources shared between several threads should be created before threads enter concurrent access to those resources.

Comment: `while (!::PostThreadMessage( threadId, WM_NULL, 0, NULL )) ::Sleep(0);` - alternatively have the thread post a message back and call `::WaitMessage` right after `CreateThread` returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CreateEvent` to create an event handle on which you let wait thread A. The first thing you do in thread B is signalling that event.

```
struct thread_data {
    /* ... */
    HANDLE started_event;
};
```

Thread A:

```
/* We can create this on the stack. We wait for thread_B to
 * copy it into its own stack before signalling the event. */
struct thread_data td;

td.started_event = CreateEvent(
    NULL  /* security attributes */,
    FALSE /* manual reset (=NO) */,
    FALSE /* initially signalled (=NO) */,
    NULL  /* name (=none) */ );

CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread_B, &td, 0, NULL);
WaitForSingleObject(td.started_event, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(td.started_event);
```

Thread B:

```
DWORD WINAPI thread_B(LPVOID data)
{
    /* local copy of thread data */
    thread_data td = *((thread_data*)data);
    SetEvent(td.started_event);

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: When you are using C++, i would recommend to use CEvent class of ATL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efk30beh.aspx

Comment: @AcidJunkie: CEvent is just a wrapper around events created using CreateEvent. There's no benefit in using that class, except some (admittedly little) overhead added to it.

Comment: Especially since `CEvent` is part of ATL, and ATL implies ActiveX/COM, which the app may not be using at all.

Comment: Considering the limitations of CreateThread this really ought to use beginthread.

Comment: @Voo: CreateThread offers quite the same as beginthread and CreateThreadEx is very much like beginthreadex.

Comment: @datenwolf You mean apart from the whole "You can't use the standard C library if you use `CreateThread` part" right? Which personally I do consider somewhat of a downside.

Comment: @Voo: that's no longer true.

Comment: @Harry It's certainly still documented as true even for Windows 8.1 and most people probably want to support previous versions as well even if it was fixed there..

Comment: @Voo: there are only two potential issues that I'm aware of: a memory leak, and an edge case when memory or address space is extremely low.  The documentation for CreateThread no longer mentions the memory leak, presumably because it only applies in Windows XP or earlier, and even then only if the runtime is linked statically.  The edge case is of little practical concern in most (almost all) contexts.  If you're using the thread pool, or any other Windows API that creates threads for you, you don't get to choose how the thread is created anyway.

Comment: @Harry I had to fix bugs where instead of nicely degrading when memory ran low, the application crashed with strange non deterministic errors. Anyhow that's the difference between what's *documented* and how the implementation currently works. Relying on implementation behavior is a bad idea (MS would be perfectly in their right to just call `abort` if you called *any* CRT function in the next version of windows from such a thread), particularly if there's a supported API that does everything `CreateThread` does and is documented to work correctly with the CRT.

Comment: @Voo: the problem with calling _beginthreadex just because the docs say so is simply that you don't always have the option.  If you're using the thread pool, or any other API, library or framework that creates threads for you, you don't get to choose how the threads are launched.  Microsoft *has* to continue to support this scenario, or else nobody could use the thread pool - and Microsoft are *very* fond of the thread pool.  IMO if you're obliged to use generic Win32 threads some of the time, you're better off doing so all of the time simply for consistency.  YMMV.

Comment: @Voo: the special case, of course, is where (for some reason or other) you have to be able to cope with low memory conditions.  That [just came up recently in another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489007/multithreaded-application-crashes-with-errors-r6016-or-0xc0000005-at-high-memory).  Since you've had actual experience with this situation, you might like to weigh in?

Comment: @Harry Never used the win32 thread pool, but looking at its documentation I don't see any requirement of it using `CreateThread`, so even if MS used it now, they could easily change to using `_beginthread` and fix the bugs. Sure if I use an API I can only hope that it doesn't have bugs in it, but why introduce bugs in your own code just to be consistently buggy? Anyhow - looks like a likely cause of the bug in the linked question, interesting what you could do if the thread creation isn't under your control.. looks bad.

Comment: @Voo: the thread pool can't use _beginthread, because not all applications that use it are linked to the C runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Your scenario is that you have two threads between which messages are sent. The parent thread needs to send messages, but the child thread needs to perform initialization before it is able to receive. This creates a temporal dependency.

One option is to use an event to let the child signal to the parent that it has completed its initialization and is ready to receive messages. The parent creates the event, passes it to the thread, and then waits on the event. The thread performs its initialization and then signals the event.

This approach works perfectly well but to me it seems needlessly complex. Why start a thread and then block until it has performed work? That, to me, defeats the purpose of threading.

So the alternative is to avoid this blocking. Since the parent thread cannot proceed until the initialization of the message queue structures are performed, let's move that initialization to the parent thread. Then there is no need for an event and no need to block.

1. Initialize message queue structures in parent thread.
2. Create child thread passing message queue structure.
3. Enqueue messages.